# regex parsing a string with an optional substring and preserve both

Tags: regex, substring

I have the following strings, with substring between the square brackets is optional, so it would come in 2 variations:

Standard Eastern Time[HH:mm]

Standard Eastern Time

I'd like to use regular expression to get both "Standard Eastern Time" and HH:mm (if [HH:mm] exists)

I've tried various regex:

(.+)[(.*)]

does not works when [HH:mm] exists

(.+)([(.*)])?

just includes everything

Any help or pointers is appreciative.

Comment: Is the first part of the string always "Standard Eastern Time"?  If so, there isn't much of a reason to capture it in the first place.  Anyway, I think the main issue you're running into here is the fact that the square brackets `[` and `]` are special characters in regex.  If you want to capture them literally, you'll need to escape them with \.  Try something like `(.+)\[(.*)\]` (note: you could actually just do `(.+)\[(.*)]` since the right bracket is only a special character when following a left bracket, but I escaped it anyway for clarity.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nM0xU8

Comment: @Sam, nice answer. (Why did you make it a comment, instead of a "real" answer?)  
For the sake of completeness and future-proofing, I will quote your actual regex here, in case that link ever goes bust:  
`^([^\[]*)(\[([^\]]*)\])?`.  
I personally would also make that second group *non-capturing*, just for the sake of documenting the fact that we don't care about it:  
`^([^\[]*)(?:\[([^\]]*)\])?`.

Comment: @Edward to be honest: didn't feel like writing out a full answer, and just quoting a regex isn't deserving of an answer.  Thank you for future proofing and adding the non-capturing group.

Comment: Sam, thank you for the expression, it's working. I'll review it in detail and will try to understand it :)

Comment: Austin, no, Standard Eastern Time is a portion I'd like to capture as well: it's a representation of different time zone names. The regex you provided cannot parse this string: "Standard Eastern Time". Sorry if my previous post is unclear. Thanks for trying.